# double dot above r

Tags: amsmath, superscripts

I'd like to type the double dots above $r$ as in the last line of the snippet.

How ?

[image]

Comment: Did you try `\ddot{r}`?

Comment: Look at table 236 in the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List that you can find using the question linked as duplicate.

Comment: @egreg `\ddot{r}` works thanks. But I do not understand your sentence: ` that you can find using the question linked as duplicate` as I'm not a native speaker; could you reword it ?